# JENKINS job is failed even if ROBOCOPY command successfully executed in a BAT script

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, robocopy

I am executing a windows bat script through jenkins. Batch file is giving the desired output,however build is failing.My batch file is..

```
cd /d D:\\Bank\\Member\\ID

if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

mkdir OTP

if %errorlevel% neq 0 exit /b %errorlevel%

robocopy C:\Corporate D:\\Bank\\Member\\ID\ /E /XF  *.bat

if %errorlevel% neq 1 exit /b %errorlevel%

cd /d D:\\Bank\\Staff\\ID
```

ROBOCOPY GIVES EXIT CODE 1 AFTER SUCESSFULLY COPYING FILES.
BUT JENKINS FAILS BUILD AND GIVING BELOW ERROR:

```
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I Want the build to be successful if `robocopy` exits code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10952344/6309), the first criteria to check is the account used to run Jenkins.
Type `services.msc` to open the Windows services and look for the Jenkins service.

Instead of "Local Service Account", use your own account: that will avoid any right issue.

But: the other criteria is to display the error code.
As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27166124/6309):

> All exit codes up to '3' are fine.

So after `robocopy`, you can add:

```
@echo robocopy exit code: %ERRORLEVEL%
@if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 3 ( echo robocopy ERROR )
@if %ERRORLEVEL% GTR 3 ( exit %ERRORLEVEL% )
@set ERRORLEVEL=0
REM at the end:
exit /b 0
```

That will ensure Jenkins don't fail the batch step, even though the original error level for robocopy was 1.

Comment: I have already tried it but it's not working.I am getting the same error message as was in the question...@VonC

Comment: @rohit.dagur did you try checking the errorlevel, and setting it to 0?

Comment: yes...i did check it..and set it but i result is same..@VonC

Comment: @rohit.dagur can you add `exit /b 0` at then end of your script?

Answer (score 2):

My best advise would be to use jenkins-pipeline, try/catch block, and use bat commands as few as possible (or do not use at all).

But considering your case there's a simple solution as well: just set the field "ERRORLEVEL to set build unstable" to 1 (or other suitable number). The field appears if you click "Advanced" button under the "Execute Windows batch command" block:

[image]

This method will check your build as "Unstable", but will continue to execute.

Comment: I don't want to make the build failed.Jenkins executes bat file successfuly but at the end it marked build as failed...@n01d

Comment: It will mark build as "Unstable" on exitcode 1 -- not "Failed".

Answer (score 1):

please use like following to avoid:

```
bat "robocopy /s source dest & EXIT /B 0"
```

The above will continue the jenkins build even if robocopy returns non-zero errorlevel. Robocopy does not return 0 for various reasons even after successfull copy, as it compared the two folders. Please lookup for it's return code to know more details